# python - path to chromedriver.exe (running on server)

Tags: python, selenium, server

I used to run a program on my computer, and all works fine..
Once I started running it on a server using Flask and Thread, I cant upload a chrome driver file

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "chromedriver.exe", options = options)
```

The file is in the same directory, maybe because it's running on the server I need a different path.
Which path to file is the right one?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need `chromedriver.exe` to pass it like that. You can use **auto installer** in this case.

Simply do this :-

```
pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller
```

and then initialize the browser like this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

If you pay attention, we have not hardcoded the path in

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`, and still it will be able to take the latest chromedriver everytime you run your script. Basically say good bye to `chromedriver.exe` and the tedious job to upgrade it, whenever we have a new build from chromium.

Comment: How can we set
<code> driver = webdriver.Chrome (options = options) </code>

Comment: you need to define chromeoptions for that. see everything is same, it just a auto installer. so remove that `chromedriver.exe` from `webdriver.Chrome(options = options)`